# What is the inverse Laplace transform of the equation? $F(s)=\frac{1}{s\left( s^2 +s+1\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, computational-mathematics, inverse-laplace

$F(s)=\frac{1}{s\left( s^2 +s+1\right)}$

Can you help me? Is there someone to explain step by step?

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the problem, it is the way it works on this site. Please always provide context for the question, show what you tried and where is the problem on the road. In this case, which is the partial fraction decomposition of $F(s)$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{s\left( s^{2} +s+1\right)} =\frac{s^{2} +s+1-(s^{2} +s)}{s\left( s^{2} +s+1\right)} =\frac{1}{s} -\frac{s+1}{s^{2} +s+1}\\
=\frac{1}{s} -\frac{s+1}{\left( s+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2}}\\
=\frac{1}{s} -\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{\left( s+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2}} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left( s+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2}}\\
L^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) =1\\
L^{-1}\left(\frac{s+a}{( s+a)^{2} +b^{2}}\right) =e^{-at}\cos bt\\
L^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{( s+a)^{2} +b^{2}}\right) =e^{-at}\sin bt
\end{gather*}
Can you use the information provided to get at the final answer?

(Hint: Do some rearranging.)